# highlighting difference in text

Tags: swift, string, parsing, text

i want to highlight the text differences between two strings. First string is correct string , second is the inputed string by the user. It shows the spelling and grammatical errors between the two. Example below
[image]

I have a solution that checks each word , then each letter, it does work to some degree but not every case. Is there a better way of doing it?

An another example where it does not work properly.

[image]

"The" should be completely red, in soldiers just "i" and "s" should be red. All of "into the" should be red.

```
func colorTextDiff(correctStr:String, answerText:String) -> NSAttributedString {

        var hintTextIndex = 0

        let attribute = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: correctStr)

        attribute.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black , range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: correctStr.count))
        attribute.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:14.0), range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: correctStr.count))

        let correctWords = correctStr.split(separator: " ")
        var answerWords = answerText.split(separator: " ")

        var answerWordIndex = 0
        //match on words, when a word doesnt match test the word's character
        for correctWord in correctWords {
            if answerWordIndex>=answerWords.count { break}
            let answerWord = answerWords[answerWordIndex]
            var wrongChar = 0, answerCharIndex = 0
            print("words ", correctWord, " ", answerWord)
            if correctWord.lowercased() != answerWord.lowercased() {
                for c in correctWord {
                    if answerCharIndex>=answerWord.count {
                        let len = correctWord.count-answerCharIndex
                        attribute.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red , range: NSRange.init(location: hintTextIndex, length: len))
                        hintTextIndex += len+1
                        break
                    }
                    let correctChar = String(c)
                    let answerChar = String(answerWord)[answerCharIndex..<answerCharIndex+1]
                    print("chars ", correctChar, " ", answerChar)
                    if correctChar.lowercased() != answerChar.lowercased() {
                        print("hint index: ", hintTextIndex)
                        attribute.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red , range: NSRange.init(location: hintTextIndex+1, length: 1))
                        wrongChar+=1
                    }

                    answerCharIndex+=1

                    hintTextIndex+=1
                }

            } else {
                hintTextIndex += correctWord.count+1
            }
            if(wrongChar<correctWord.count) {answerWordIndex+=1 } //probably a missed word not missed typed word
        }




        hintTextIndex+=1
        return attribute
}
```

Comment: i added a doesnt work case

Comment: yes i know thats why i am asking here

Comment: I would  start by separating out the finding of differences from  the coloring of the string. Those are 2 separate tasks and putting the code for both into 1 place makes it much harder  to understand either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a cool problem.

Here's my solution:

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
  func setCharacterColor(at location: Int) {
    let range = NSRange(location: location, length: 1)
    self.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: range)
  }
}


extension Array where Element == Character {
  func index(of character: Character, greaterThan index: Int) -> Int? {
    for i in index...self.count where self[i] == character {
      return i
    }
    return nil
  }
}


let correctString = "The soldiers stormed into the village just after sunrise"
let incorrectString = "solder stormed village just after sunrise"
let correctArray = Array(correctString)
let incorrectArray = Array(incorrectString)
var correctMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: correctString)

var currentPosition = 0
for char in incorrectArray {
  guard let position = correctArray.index(of: char, greaterThan: currentPosition) else {
    continue
  }
  while currentPosition < position {
    correctMutableString.setCharacterColor(at: currentPosition)
    currentPosition = currentPosition + 1
  }
  currentPosition = position + 1
}

labelCorrect.attributedText = correctMutableString
labelIncorrect.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: incorrectString)
```

[image]

It's still order n squared but this problem is always going to be rather computensive.

It works by looping until it finds a character in the correct string where the character matches a character in the incorrect string. It then highlights all the characters it passes over during that process. The key is that it only highlights new characters never ones that it has already looped over previously.

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution i will try it later, thanks. I was wondering how to highlight text in the answer. For example "solder stormed a village" , would highlight the "a" since it doesn't exist in the correct sentence.